# How to uncheck all checkboxes when i close a modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I want to pop up a modal on clicking the checkbox. And wants to uncheck it when I close a modal automatically.

I tried both attr and prop methods. None of them worked.

```
//uncheck all when modal closes 
$(document).on('click', '#closeInvoiceModal', function() {
    $('.creditCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
});
```

This was expected to uncheck all the checkboxes having the same class '.creditCheckbox'. But none of them didn't close.

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="invoiceDetail{{$loop->iteration}}"
            name="invoiceDetail{{$loop->iteration}}"
            class="filled-in chk-col-green invoiceCheckbox"
            data-campaignId="{{$item['id']}}"/>
   <label class="invoiceDetailLink" for="invoiceDetail{{$loop- 
            >iteration}}">Inv. Details</label>
</td>

<!--Modal html code-->
<div class="modal fade" id="cbreInvoiceDetailsModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Full screen view</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data- 
                 dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> 
                 </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
                    <div class="box_layout" id="show-data">
                        <div class="image_layout">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="closeInvoiceModal" type="button" 
                    class="btn btn-sm btn-success waves-effect 
                     pull-right" data- 
             dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your html code too

Comment: <div class="modal fade" id="cbreInvoiceDetailsModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

Comment: <!--checkbox html code--> <label class="invoiceDetailLink" for="invoiceDetail{{$loop->iteration}}">Inv. Details</label><input type="checkbox" id="invoiceDetail{{$loop->iteration}}"
                           name="invoiceDetail{{$loop->iteration}}"
                           class="filled-in chk-col-green invoiceCheckbox"
                           data-campaignId="{{$item['id']}}"/>

Comment: please try this once,
$('#closeInvoiceModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  $('.creditCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
})

Comment: @yashdubey. I tried but didn't work.

Comment: @VISHNUPRASAD.M.R.  edit your question and add your html code there

Comment: `$('.creditCheckbox').each(function () {
 $(this).prop('checked', false);
});` try looping it.

Comment: @VISHNUPRASAD.M.R., please provide your HTML code. thanks.

Comment: @JavascriptGeek. Added html code.

Comment: @Shubham. Tried looping. Not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use this code I hope it's work for you.

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
         $('.creditCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

Comment: Not working. Also, my modal id was different. Not myModal.

Comment: you are using bootstrap model, right? 
this one https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/
please check your code or send me your HTML code 
thanks

Comment: I am unable to find class `.creditCheckbox` in your HTML it mean checkbox please put the `class=creditCheckbox` in your checkbox.

Comment: Sorry, yeah that was the mistake. I accidentally used some other checkboxes class name. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have to make an example like your code, please review once, hope it will help you, it is working for me.
Thanks.

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" class="checkOption"> check 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" class="checkOption"> check 2
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" class="checkOption"> check 3
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" class="checkOption"> check 4
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cbreInvoiceDetailsModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!--Modal html code-->
<div class="modal fade" id="cbreInvoiceDetailsModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Full screen view</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> 
                 </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
                    <div class="box_layout" id="show-data">
                        <div class="image_layout">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="closeInvoiceModal" type="button" 
                    class="btn btn-sm btn-success waves-effect pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cbreInvoiceDetailsModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
      $('.checkOption').prop('checked', false);
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: This also helps. I used wrong class name .Thank you.